# bash using column on echo -e formatted text

Tags: bash, formatting

I am trying to create bash script for checking headers for abaqus includes. 
Main used functions are grep, echo and column.

Output should be table with highlighted errors (just checking strings, if string is not correct, I expect it to print red.)
Table is fine without formatting. As soon as I start to use bold formatting in echo -e, the column function stops working.

Does anybody know how to fix it?

header inc1.inc:

```
**
** label = AAAAA
** project = /Data/BBB/CCC
** phase = VD
**
```

table without formatting (as expected):

```
submodel   label   project            phase  
inc1.inc   AAAAA   /Data/BBB/CCC      VD     
inc2.inc   YY      /Data/ZZ/Z         VPP    
inc3.inc   PPP-23  /Data/OP/HJK22/OK  KKKKK
```

table with bold formatting of first row and first column (bold formatting cannot be shown, please try to execute the code in console):

```
submodel   label         project                    phase        
inc1.inc   AAAAA   /Data/BBB/CCC      VD     
inc2.inc   YY      /Data/ZZ/Z         VPP    
inc3.inc   PPP-23  /Data/OP/HJK22/OK  KKKKK
```

code:

```
#!/bin/bash

### ========== variables ==========
FORMATRESET="\e[0m"
FORMATBOLD="\e[1m"
FORMATERROR="\e[1;5;48;5;9m"

PATTERNS=("label" "project" "phase")

### ========== functions ==========
HCK () {
echo -e -n "${FORMATBOLD}submodel${FORMATRESET}\t"
  for PATTERN in ${PATTERNS[@]}; do
  echo -e -n "${FORMATBOLD}${PATTERN}${FORMATRESET}\t"
  done
echo

  for SUBMODEL in $@; do
  echo -e -n "${FORMATBOLD}${SUBMODEL%\*\*}${FORMATRESET}\t"
    for PATTERN in ${PATTERNS[@]}; do
    FOUND=($(grep "** ${PATTERN}" ${SUBMODEL} | awk '{print $4}'))
    echo -e -n "${RESETFORMAT}${FOUND}${RESETFORMAT}\t"
    done
  echo
  done
}

HCKwoFORMATTING () {
echo -e -n "submodel\t"
  for PATTERN in ${PATTERNS[@]}; do
  echo -e -n "${PATTERN}\t"
  done
echo

  for SUBMODEL in $@; do
  echo -e -n "${SUBMODEL%\*\*}\t"
    for PATTERN in ${PATTERNS[@]}; do
    FOUND=($(grep "** ${PATTERN}" ${SUBMODEL} | awk '{print $4}'))
    echo -e -n "${FOUND}\t"
    done
  echo
  done
}

### ========== execution ==========
HCK * |column -t -s $'\t'
echo
HCKwoFORMATTING * | column -t -s $'\t'
```

Comment: [This question from UNIX StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121107/a-shell-tool-to-tablify-input-data-containing-ansi-escape-codes) might help. The accepted answer uses a dozen or so lines of `awk` code as a color-compatible replacement for the `column` command.

Comment: @MikeHolt thanks for help. The script is finished now.